# text object for highlighted text

Tags: cursor-motions, object-motions

If I have a file that contains

```
this_is_the_first_underscore_phrase
this_is_the_first_underscore_phrase
```

I search for "first" `/first` and my cursor is placed onto the start of the word "first".

I know I can change this word by doing `ct_` but I wonder if there's a different way, is there a way to "change inside currently highlighted text" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
gnc
```

`gn` will do a visual selection of the search result, then `c` is, as you know, `change`.

Also, `cgn` works (change the next occurence of the search result).

Comment: Awesome (will accept in 9 mins), had no idea that existed. How can I discover this for myself in the future?

Comment: Read articles about Vim, videos, stackoverflow posts and browse the help of Vim too. I'd say that's where I learn the most

Comment: Related [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Operating on search matches using gn](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/)

Comment: @theonlygusti :help and :helpgrep are my go-tos

Comment: @D.BenKnoble what's the process meant to be for `:help`? I tried to search help for `highlight` and `search` and `object` but it wasn't helpful to me for answering my question. Maybe there's a better way to search the help pages

Comment: @theonlygusti for searching i like `:helpgrep`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks, don't know `:helpgrep`  exists.

Comment: @theonlygusti if you are looking for text-objects, start reading at `:h text-objects`. And note, the `gn` and `gN` is mentioned right there.